# Browser inside of a browser

Tags: ajax, flash, silverlight, browser, iframe

I am not trying to track clicks or anything like other people - I just want to put a browser within a browser that can go back, forward, refresh, accept user-entered URLs, and store bookmarks.  Can flash/silverlight/ajax/whatever do this?  If so, how?

Comment: have a look at this:
http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Comment: That is mainly for navigation and not for browsing, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**Solution 1:**

1. Create or use an existing [ActiveX Web Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx) control.
2. And let your web/page host that `ActiveX`, or host multiple controls.

**Solution 2:**

1. Put an `iframe` inside a `UserControl`, a textbox and a go button.
2. Get the user provided url from textbox.
3. Change the `src` of the `iframe` when user clicks the `go` button.

_

```
<iframe id="iFrame" name="myFrame" src="http://bing.com" 
                                     width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0">
<p>Does your browser support iframes?</p>
</iframe>
```

**--EDIT--**

This is in response to your comment; you posed 3 questions:

For 1, thats correct, `ActiveX` works for IE, more specifically for Windows; there are ways you can install ActiveX for different browsers, but it(the ActiveX) would require windows OS. See [this](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex).

For 2, try handling that using JavaScript; something like following within iframe block.

```
<p><a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a></p>
```

Checkout [these examples](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JavaScript-Create-Back-Button-In-Iframe).

For the third one, if I understand you correctly then you can always parse the url when user clicks onto the `Go` button; and respond accordingly before rendering the page.

Comment: ActiveX would only work in IE, right?

And for the iframe how would i do forward, backwards, and refresh?  and can i pull the URL when it's out of the originating domain?

Answer (score 0):

flash can do basic html (AFAIK) not sure about silverlight.
you will struggle to do it with javascript/iframes. Especially back/forward/refresh buttons. If you are on the same domain you have some control over the iframe, but once it leaves your domain, you lose control

Comment: do you have any info about flash?  I need those four main functions.

Comment: Sorry, 5 functions.  And it won't be in the same domain, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry no info about flash, mainly assumed from the fact that textblocks in flash can have html in it, but only very very basic html (its something like b tags work, but strongs don't etc)

Answer (score 0):

Would using an iframe or an object with type="text/html" be useful to you in terms of being able to embed a page within a page? Either method effectively permits loading a separate page within a page with little side-effect.

Comment: An iframe would work if I could get refresh, pull the current URL (off domain), and forwards/backwards to work.